# Centering grouped inline elements issue

Tags: html, css, center

I have a section that I want to look as if it is centered on the page. I have four boxes that appear `inline` and I believe the reason they do not like they are centered is because everything is aligned naturally to the left. The thing is, I do not want the content that is in these boxes to be centered, I want them aligned left.

So how can I make the boxes appear as if they are centered within the page, but not have it affect my text?

```css
#contact-connect {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 10%;
  padding: 80px 0;
}

#contact-connect-box-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}

.contact-connect-box {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 60px 0 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition:1s; -webkit-transition:1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-connect">
    <div id="contact-connect-box-container">
        <div class="contact-connect-box">
            <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Call</h2>
            <div class="contact-connect-description">vcxv</div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-connect-box">
            <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Write</h2>
            <div class="contact-connect-description">
                Reach out to us
                <br>
                <div id="scroll" class="contact-connect-link">Fill out our contact form.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-connect-box">
            <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Visit</h2>
            <div class="contact-connect-description">
                fgrge
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-connect-box">
            <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Connect</h2>
            <div class="contact-connect-description">
                <div class="contact-connect-link"><a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">Visit us on Facebook</a></div>
                <div class="contact-connect-link"><a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank">See us on Youtube</a></div>
                <div class="contact-connect-link"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it look how you want if you remove the Connect box?

Comment: Use the standard `text-align:center` on the divs and override it on their children. Otherwise we're looking at flexbox I suspect. Depends on your your requirements.

Comment: It doesn't appear `text-align: center` and left worked, unless I did it wrong.

Comment: There's a couple of things going on here...one is that you border/padding are adding to the widths (that can be fixed by adding `box-sizing:border-box`) the other is the [**space between inline-block elements**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: @Paulie_D the snippet altered my code. I do not have any inline-block spacing on my page and I do not have borders either. I just added that to better show the 4 different sections and the issue at hand.

Comment: You **do** have borders...they are clearly stated in the CSS provided and `inline-block` items have spacing **by default**. That's why you need to use the techiniques linked to remove it.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't have borders or `inline-block` spacing issues on my actual page. The snippet was merely a quick example to help show this. I am using `inline-block` techniques to remove the spacing and borders are NOT on my page. The issue is the left align making this not look centered.

Comment: I have told you why. READ. Nor does the border or `inline-block` issues within my snippet have ANYTHING to do with the question. The issue is still present with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add "display: flex" on your #contact-connect-box-container

```
#contact-connect-box-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

DEMO :
https://jsfiddle.net/w776Lq1u/8/

Comment: My issue is I do not have the borders on the actual page, so it still doesn't appeared centered.

Comment: Then just don't set a specific width for the individual boxes.

Comment: How else would I do it??

Comment: Can't you remove  `width: 25%;` from `.contact-connect-box`?

Comment: No, that would bunch everything together. I need the separation and in a responsive way.

Comment: Then add some padding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111239/discussion-between-stackunderflow-and-becky).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the margin on the right side of "Connect."  I would recommend using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and using `display: flex; justify-content: space-around;`  That way you won't need any margins at all.

EDIT:  [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AJt9ijYVBv9CyZRer1rZ?p=preview)

Comment: Didn't help. It still doesn't look centered. It is because everything is aligned  to the left.

Comment: Don't align anything.

Comment: Text is naturally aligned to the left and that is how I want it. I don't actually have `align: left;` in my code.

Comment: I have updated my comment with a plnkr that shows you exactly what I'm talking about.